# ASP.NET: Set multiple CheckBox.Checked based on list of ID's from a query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set multiple checkboxes to checked based off of a list of CheckBox ID's.
Here is an example:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="TS_Deviation" runat="server" />
```

code behind

```
int i = clist.Count -1;
do
{
    clist[i].Checked = true;
    i--;
} while (clist != null && i >= 0);
```

The list contains the CheckBox ID's to be set to checked.
for example, `clist[0]` would contain `"TS_Deviation"` in plain text.
The reason I am trying to set the value through a list is because the list is coming from a linq query, which pulls every checkbox's ID that needs to be set to `checked = true`.
My problem is I have no idea how to use clist[i] as a checkbox ID to set it to checked.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: and whats the problem? are you getting any errors?

Comment: I thought my question was clear, just to clarify I added what my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list contains the IDs in "plaintext", I'm assuming you mean the ID strings?

If so, you need to call [`Control.FindControl( ... )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to get the actual checkbox based on its ID. Be aware that this is not a recursive function, so it only finds direct child controls. If your checkboxes are inside a container, ie:

```
<asp:Panel ID="CheckboxContainer" runat="server"> .... checkboxes .... </asp:Panel>
```

Then you would call:

```
var check = CheckboxContainer.FindControl( clist[i] ) as CheckBox;
```

To get the checkbox. If will return a control, so you need to cast it to `CheckBox` before it is possible to call the `.Checked` property.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the linq query select the actual Checkbox object and set the property on that?

If not you can use to find the control on the page using the id you have.

```
Page.FindControl(clist[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Find Control method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
int i = clist.Count -1;
do
{    
    CheckBox cb= (CheckBox)Page.FindControl.Find(clist[0], true);     
    cb.Checked = true;
    i--;
} while (clist != null && i >= 0);
```

edit: Sorry, fixed for webforms.

Comment: `Controls.Find( ... )` is a winforms method, and the question is about ASP.Net.